# How do i search for Mentors outside of my academic sphere?

Tags: phd, mentoring

I recently discovered a YouTuber who offers advice regarding the journey of pursuing a PhD. This content creator recommended seeking a mentor beyond the academic sphere to address challenges associated with your Ph.D. effectively. This leads me to wonder: Is being formally assigned a mentor possible? If it is indeed possible, where should I begin my search for such a mentoring relationship?

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean by "beyond the academic sphere" ? Outside your institute ?

Comment: I would attach the link here, i hope that is okay.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoMgRqBkBIU&t=268s
The point comes up around 3:45, where it is pretty much straightforward, go out and ask someone to mentor me. I would like to ask, If i do so, would I really be accepted as a mentee?

Comment: I think a fundamental problem here is what you imagine "formally assigned a mentor" could mean. This really doesn't make sense outside of specific academic or other settings, where a senior person is over-seeing you. It has no operational sense "in the larger world"... Can you clarify?

Comment: @kc_nul You need to be able to explain your question clearly *here*, not through a video hosted on some other site. We want questions and answers here to be broadly useful, and outside links might die and it's not a good path to people finding that *this* question is relevant to them unless the question is described fully *here*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you are looking for just having a life advice from a person who has done it, there are ample opportunities. A cold call might not be a great idea. Usually, you can talk to someone during an event at the university, find them in some Common hobbies you pursue (sports, toastmaster, cultural organization) or attend some university organized meet and greets. If you just want to meet someone quarterly and have a sanity check, you can easily find a mentor in such gatherings